# How can I say that someone doesn't seem happy for a specific reason?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a short text and I got stuck because I wanted to write that my parents, who are now at home not working seeing that they retired from work, seem to be unhappy. Can I say something like: 両親は働かないで嬉しくなさそうです?

Comment: If it were me, I'd say that you're pretty much there.  I might have chosen a different wording, but it looks good from my (admittedly foreign) perspective.

Comment: It looks very "translated" and not natural.  Luckily, you have received a good answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna say, "両親は定年になってからというもの、毎日つまらなさそうにしています．"

It literally means "Ever since my parents retired from their work, they look miserable."

Or respecting your original words, I would revise as "両親は働いていないので、楽しくなさそうです."

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 〜みたいです。みたい can be used to express your opinion or assumption based on what you have seen first hand. “It looks like”/ “It seems like”. そう I believe is more commonly used for things you've heard.

。。。毎日つまらないみたいです。

[More from Maggie Sensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/11/11/how-to-use-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-mitai/)